# Can you switch between different views programmatically using RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Let's say I have 3 different views using RelativeLayout for an AppWidget.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/item0" android:visibility="visible"> </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/item1" android:visibility="gone"> </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/item2" android:visibility="gone"> </RelativeLayout>
```

Will I be able to programmatically switch between views?

Answer (score 2):

yes , using [RemoteViews.setViewVisibility(int id, int visibility)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setViewVisibility%28int,%20int%29)